# How to go to another layout by radio button?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have 2 codes one in .java and another in .xml file .. I need to make `RadioButton` take me to another page which have all the times which available for every doctor . Such as this :

**morningdrs.xml** has this code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MorningDrsGeneral" >




<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="enter your name please : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Day / Name Of available Doctors "
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/qwe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radiob1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="8:00 - 8:30" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radiob2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9:00 - 9:30" />


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radiob3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9:30 - 10:00" />
            </RadioGroup>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sunday "
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.kamal Garaibeh" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.hussain Al-Hais" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/qwe1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday "
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.Shadi Hammouri" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.nawwaf Shatnawi" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.Mohammad Bani-hani" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/qwe2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tuesday "
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Dr.Rami Yaghoti" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.tareq Al-jabri" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.Fahmi talab" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/qwe3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wednsday "
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Dr.Fuad Ammari" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.Mohammad Bani-Hani" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.Khaled Obeidat" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/qwe4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thursday "
                android:textColor="@color/Red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

       <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Dr.Ghazi qasaimeh" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dr.abdul-kareem hammouri" />


            </RadioGroup>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Booking" />
</TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and this is my .java file

```
 package com.example.hospitalsdirectorysystem;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


 public class MorningDrsGeneral extends ActionBarActivity {
     Button button ;
     EditText et;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.morningdrs);


     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

so when click booking button i want this button take me to another layout and if the time is reserved i need an alert to say this to user and if not reserved it will write his name under the time .

Answer (score 0):

Setup your radio groups with the code:

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);
```

Then set an `onCheckedChangedListener` (`radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {...});`) to them and test for the checked ID using a switch:

```
switch (checkedId) {
    case R.id.yourButton:
        setContentView(...);
        break;
    case R.id.yourOtherButton:
        setContentView(...);
        break;
}
```